# How to fetch data of multiple users using gorm?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

Database: MySql
I have a two structs as follows:

```
type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name    string
    Address string
}

type Address struct {
    gorm.Model
    PersonID int
    Address  []Address
}
```

I want to fetch data of multiple persons with there adresses.
I tried it like:

```
var result []Person
db.Table("persons").Select("persons.id,persons.created_at, persons.updated_at,persons.deleted_at,persons.name,addresses.address").Joins("inner join addresses on addresses.person_id = persons.id").Scan(&result)
```

I got result:

```
[
  {
    ID: 13,
    CreatedAt: '2018-03-28T16:25:43+05:30',
    UpdatedAt: '2018-03-28T16:28:31+05:30',
    DeletedAt: null,
    Name: 'roshan',
    Address: null
  },
  {
    ID: 13,
    CreatedAt: '2018-03-28T16:25:43+05:30',
    UpdatedAt: '2018-03-28T16:28:31+05:30',
    DeletedAt: null,
    Name: 'roshan',
    Address: null
  },
  {
    ID: 14,
    CreatedAt: '2018-03-28T16:25:43+05:30',
    UpdatedAt: '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    DeletedAt: null,
    Name: 'kunal2',
    Address: null
  }
];
```

expexted result is

```
[
  {
    ID: 13,
    CreatedAt: '2018-03-28T16:25:43+05:30',
    UpdatedAt: '2018-03-28T16:28:31+05:30',
    DeletedAt: null,
    Name: 'roshan',
    Address: ['pune', 'nagpur']
  },
  {
    ID: 14,
    CreatedAt: '2018-03-28T16:25:43+05:30',
    UpdatedAt: '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    DeletedAt: null,
    Name: 'kunal2',
    Address: ['New York']
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you probably should change your model declarations to this

```
type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name    string
    Address []Address
}

type Address struct {
    gorm.Model
    PersonID int
}
```

And then to preload associations you can use this query

```
var person []Person

err := db.Preload("Address").Find(&person).Error
```

where you person param will be te results from db with preloaded addresses

Comment: Isn't `Address` missing a `Name` field or some other data? As it is it seems pointless.

Comment: Person too missing probably some data but i think kunal provided minimal object because other field are not necessary to include for his issue